# How can I redirect to paypal in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway

I have the following in my view:

```
<a href="{{route('payment.paypal')}}">Pay with PayPal</a>
```

Defined the route:

```
Route::get('pay-with-paypal', 'CheckoutController@payWithPaypal')->name('payment.paypal');
```

My CheckoutController looks like the one below:

```
use Srmklive\PayPal\Services\ExpressCheckout;

class CheckoutController extends Controller
{
    public function payWithPaypal(){

        $provider = new ExpressCheckout; 
        $data = [];
        $data['items'] = [
            [
                'name' => 'Product 1',
                'price' => 9.99,
                'qty' => 1
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Product 2',
                'price' => 4.99,
                'qty' => 2
            ]
        ];

        $data['invoice_id'] = 1;
        $data['invoice_description'] = "Order #{$data['invoice_id']} Invoice";
        $data['return_url'] = url('/');
        $data['cancel_url'] = url('/');

        $total = 0;
        foreach($data['items'] as $item) {
            $total += $item['price']*$item['qty'];
        }

        $data['total'] = $total;

        $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data);

         // This will redirect user to PayPal
        return redirect($response['paypal_link']);

    }
}
```

My config looks like this:

```
return [
    'mode'    => 'sandbox', // Can only be 'sandbox' Or 'live'. If empty or invalid, 'live' will be used.
    'sandbox' => [
        'username'    => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_USERNAME', ''),
        'password'    => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_PASSWORD', ''),
        'secret'      => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_SECRET', ''),
        'certificate' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_CERTIFICATE', ''),
        'app_id'      => 'APP-80W284485P519543T', // Used for testing Adaptive Payments API in sandbox mode
    ],
    'live' => [
        'username'    => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_USERNAME', ''),
        'password'    => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_PASSWORD', ''),
        'secret'      => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_SECRET', ''),
        'certificate' => env('PAYPAL_LIVE_API_CERTIFICATE', ''),
        'app_id'      => '', // Used for Adaptive Payments API
    ],

    'payment_action' => 'Sale', // Can only be 'Sale', 'Authorization' or 'Order'
    'currency'       => 'USD',
    'billing_type'   => 'MerchantInitiatedBilling',
    'notify_url'     => '', // Change this accordingly for your application.
    'locale'         => '', // force gateway language  i.e. it_IT, es_ES, en_US ... (for express checkout only)
    'validate_ssl'   => true, // Validate SSL when creating api client.
];
```

My .env is also configured:

```
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_USERNAME=example-facilitator_api1.hotmail.com
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_PASSWORD=SLU2YLP4B
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_SECRET=TF3K8CtWTEmAcRu40.XWAihLRko
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_API_CERTIFICATE=
```

When I click on the link "Pay with PayPal", nothing happens. Anything I could have possibly done wrong?

Reference: https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing ?

Comment: When I click on the link "Pay with PayPal", nothing happens.
Anything I could have possibly done wrong?

Comment: Have you looked in the browser dev tools to see what the response from the server is?

Comment: Yes, I looked and the status says Pending.